# Error when i use (id = true) ORMLite

Tags: java, android, ormlite

i have a class, i want put the class to ForeignCollection. In class i have field id. I did not want use `generatedId = true` , i want use my id. When i use `id = true` i have error  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not create data element in dao` , but when i use `generatedId = true` , all works good. How i can fix it?

```
@DatabaseTable
public class UserResult {

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private int id;
...
}
```

PeopleResult class: (main object)

```
 @DatabaseTable
 public class PeopleResult extends BaseModel {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private long id;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false, columnName = "resultsFC", foreignFieldName = "owner")
    private ForeignCollection<UserResult> resultsFC;


    public ForeignCollection<UserResult> getResultsFC() {
        return resultsFC;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

UserResult class (Use for ForeignCollection):

```
    @DatabaseTable
    public class UserResult extends BaseModel {

    public UserResult() {
    }

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private long id;

    @DatabaseField
    private String first_name = null;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, foreignAutoCreate = true)
    private PeopleResult owner;



    public String getFirstName() {
        return first_name == null ? "" : first_name;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried id.equal("true")?

Comment: Shouldn't it be a Long? Maybe that causes internal errors when trying to put the long in an int.

Comment: @Rituraj suman what? I do not understand you answer.

Comment: @G_V i set long type, it is do not help me

Comment: can you post the whole class? There are a number of other things to do like set an empty constructor.

Comment: @G_V i am added code to the post

Comment: How do you prevent id from clashing with an existing one if you're not generating them? Is there a particular reason you don't want to use a generated id and a separate id for programming use?

Comment: @G_V i do not want use generated id. I want set my id. i am often will use update in DataBase, i do not can use update , because every time generation new id.

Comment: If you still did not resolve your problem, please provide full log cat message and place of code which generates it.